# Wrong behavior of Inverse Fourier Transform of DiracDelta[x]/x

Tags: bugs, fourier-analysis, version-11

The following fails to compute:

```
InverseFourierTransform[DiracDelta[w]/w, w, x]
```

But if we add a,

```
InverseFourierTransform[DiracDelta[w]/w + a, w, x]
```

It evaluates the way as if DiracDelta[w]/w were zero.

Given that inverse Fourier transform is a linear operator, if the first result is unknown, so should be the second result as well.

The problem arose when I was investigating the following operator:

```
I InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[f[t], t, w]/w, w, x]
```

When `f[t]=1/t` the result was correct. But when it was `1/t+t^2` or `1/t+t`, the result was totally the same, dispite the whole operator is linear.

Comment: This is indeed strange and i confirm it on "11.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)". Seems to be a bug for me.

Comment: Works fine in v9.0.1: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ujia6.png . So it's a bug introduced after v9.0.1.